# ¿Cómo realizar una operación acumulativa sobre el mismo DataFrame en pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Partiendo del siguiente DataFrame de prueba:

```
# DataFrame Inicial
   value status  rta
0      1     in    0
1      1     in    0
2      8     on    0
3      3     in    0
```

Actualizar la columna rta, sumando los valores previos del DataFrame para registros del mismo estado.

```
# Resultado esperado
   value status  rta
0      1     in    1
1      1     in    2
2      8     on    8
3      3     in    6
```

Enfoque erroneo aplicado y datos de prueba:

```py
import pandas as pd

def my_sum(current_value, status, df):
    """
    Suma los valores anteriores del mismo estado.
    """     
    previous_value = df[df.status == status].rta.sum()
    return previous_value + current_value

def test_my_sum():
    d = {'value':[1,1,8,3], 
         'status':['in','in','on','in'],
         'rta':[0,0,0,0]}    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)    
    # La funcion anonima simpre utiliza el dataframe inicial.
    df['rta'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_sum(x.value, x.status, df), axis=1)
    print(df)

test_my_sum()

# Resultado obtenido
   value status  rta
0      1     in    1
1      1     in    1
2      8     on    8
3      3     in    3
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la línea:

```
    df['rta'] = df.apply(lambda x: my_sum(x.value, x.status, df), axis=1)
```

no es un bucle que itere por cada línea y para cada línea procesada haga la asignación `df['rta']`. Por el contrario, ejecuta "en una sola vez" las modificaciones a todas las entradas de `df` y te retorna la nueva Serie, que es la que finalmente asignas. De modo que el `df` que toma como "origen" para tus cálculos es el original, y no el resultado de cada iteración. Es cierto que internamente Pandas debe iterar para procesar el dataframe completo, pero esas iteraciones son invisibles desde Python. En lo que a ti respecta `df.apply()` no retorna hasta que no ha terminado de iterar y ha computado todos los valores, y solo entonces se asignan esos valores a `df['rta']`.

La solución a esto es evitar usar `df` como "almacén temporal" para los resultados intermedios, como tú estabas intentando. En lugar de ello tu función `my_sum()` debe ir guardando en otra parte los valores acumulados que vaya retornando.

Para esto puedes hacer uso de variables globales. Un diccionario que tenga como claves los "status" y como valores la suma de valores retornados por la función hasta ese momento sería una estructura adecuada. Pero el uso de variables globales no es buena práctica, de modo que mejor lo encapsulo en una clase:

```py
from collections import defaultdict

class MyAcum:
  def __init__(self):
    # Diccionario cuyos valores serán enteros, y 0 por defecto
    self._acum = defaultdict(int)

  def process(self, x):   # x es una copia de  la fila que está siendo procesada
    # El valor a retornar será lo que había en el acumulador, más el de la fila actual
    ret = self._acum[x.status] + x.value
    # El nuevo valor del acumulador será el que había, más el valor retornado
    self._acum[x.status] += ret
    return ret
```

Lo usarías por ejemplo así (he extendido un poco tu ejemplo con un elemento más para verificar que funciona como se esperaba):

```py
def test_myAcum():
    d = {'value':[1,1,8,3,2], 
         'status':['in','in','on','in', 'in'],
         'rta':[0,0,0,0,0]}    
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)
    acum = MyAcum()  
    df['rta'] = df.apply(acum.process, axis=1)
    print(df)
```

Prueba:

```py
>>> test_myAcum()
   value status  rta
0      1     in    1
1      1     in    2
2      8     on    8
3      3     in    6
4      2     in   11
```